ARMA model function for future unseen data with start and end dates?
I have a dataframe like this
lstvals = [30.81,27.16,82.15,31.00,9.13,11.77,25.58,7.57,7.98,7.98]

lstdates = ['2021-01-01', '2021-01-05', '2021-01-09', '2021-01-13', '2021-01-17', '2021-01-21', '2021-01-25', '2021-01-29', '2021-02-02', '2021-02-06']

data = {

    "Dates": lstdates,

    "Market Value": lstvals

}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.set_index('Dates', inplace = True)
df

I want to forecast the values which are out of this sample, for example, from '2021-02-10' to '2022-04-23' (in my dataset, I have data from '2021-01-01' to '2023-11-09', and want to forecast for next year, from '2024-01-01' to '2023-11-09)
https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/examples/notebooks/generated/statespace_forecasting.html
I have defined and fitted my model as follows, which predicts the test data:

train = df['Market Value'].iloc[:1187]
test = df['Market Value'].iloc[-200:]
...
ARMAmodel = SARIMAX(y, order = (2,1,2))
ARMAResults = ARMAmodel.fit()

...
y_pred = ARMAResults.get_forecast(len(test.index))
y_pred_df = y_pred.conf_int(alpha = 0.05) 
y_pred_df["Predictions"] = ARMAResults.predict(start = y_pred_df.index[0], end = y_pred_df.index[-1])
y_pred_df.index = test.index
y_pred_out = y_pred_df["Predictions"] 

...
plt.plot(train, color = "black")
plt.plot(test, color = "red")
plt.ylabel('Market Value ($M)')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.title("Train/Test/Prediction for Market Data")
plt.plot(y_pred_out, color='green', label = 'Predictions')
plt.legend()
plt.show()



How can I make predictions for future dates?
I have just tried to input future dates with the forecast method, and apparently, it is not working for me
ARMAResults.forecast(start = '2024-01-01', end = '2024-11-09')

TypeError: statsmodels.tsa.statespace.mlemodel.MLEResults.predict() got multiple values for keyword argument 'start'


https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/examples/notebooks/generated/statespace_forecasting.html

predict, not forecast.

with predict, I am getting 'KeyError: 'The start argument could not be matched to a location related to the index of the data.'

Issues:

Specify the frequency for the dates index:
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Dates'])
df.set_index('Dates', inplace=True)
df = df.asfreq('4D')


forecast is strictly for out-of-sample forecasts, and has no start or end parameters. (Note that its steps parameter can be passed a string or datetime type.) Either use predict or get_prediction, which support both in-sample and out-of-sample results.
ARMAResults.predict(start='2024-01-01', end='2024-11-09')

or
# mean
ARMAResults.get_prediction(start='2024-01-01', end='2024-11-09').predicted_mean 

# mean, standard error, prediction interval
ARMAResults.get_prediction(start='2024-01-01', end='2024-11-09').summary_frame()




yes, thanks - I want to forecast out of my sample (1 year into the future). so should I be using forecast or predict?

You should use predict, which can do both in-sample and out-of-sample, but crucially supports a designated start.

I see, thanks.
I also do not quite understand where I should use df = df.asfreq('4D').  If I put it after  df.set_index('Year', inplace = True) in the sample dataframe then I am getting NaN values in the Market Value column.

You also need the to_datetime call prior.

thanks!  would you say that not setting frequency (e.g. '4D', 'M', etc) could be a problem?  because I have 79 entries for each year in my subset, and there is no way to set frequency in whole days.

If not statsmodels will attempt to infer it, but generally you want to specify it.

yes, I have managed to inter it, it was something like freq='399168S'.   you have helped me a lot!
